# Secrets in databricks

Tags: scope, databricks, secret-key

I created a secret on databricks using the secrets API.

Code :

```
Scope_name : {"scope": "dbtest", "initial_manage_principal":"user"}
Resp= requests.post('https://instancename.net/mynoteid/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create',json=Scope_name)
```

Similar way, I added the user and password

Code:

```
Content = {"scope":"dbtest","key":"user","string_value":"Vidyasekar"}
requests.post('https://instancename.net/mynoteid/api/2.0/secrets/put', json=content)
```

After the execution I got response : `<Response [200]>`

Which means secrets stored successfully.

While listing the same using the list API call or `dbutils.secrets.get()`, its shows '**Secret does not exist with scope**

Here my doubt is,
How to get the databricks intance name?
Where the secrets stored in the DBFS location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of a secret scope (sample on Azure) in python would look like this:

```
import requests
import json

# Set authorization token (token is generated in user settings)
hdr = {"authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}  

x = json.dumps({'scope': 'lab-a-adls'})

r = requests.post("https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create",
    headers = hdr,
    data= x)
```

Store a credential in the scope via:

```
x = json.dumps({
  "scope": "lab-a-adls",
  "key": "credential",
  "string_value": "*******************************"
})

 r = requests.post("https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/secrets/put",
    headers = hdr,
    data= x)
```

Comment: Two things I missed here,
1. included my notebook id with the url, thats no need to include.
2. missed the header with the User Access Token.
Now its working good. Thanks Hauke :)